# Joomla 2.5 -adding extra fields to article

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

TUTORIAL: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component

When following this tutorial, and actually uploading the included ZIP file as a plugin and enabling it, I am not able to get the extra fields to show up like in the tutorial anywhere!

I am using 2.5.19. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No ideas without seeing some code but three things I would suggest:
1. update to [the latest version of 2.5](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5552-joomla-2-5-22-released.html) and 2. as this question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) and 3. add some code so we can at least figure out what you've done wrong :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to install patches 28770 and 28771

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_id=8103&tracker_item_id=28771